# Macro and Micro F1

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a binary classification problem and as the data are imbalanced I am trying to calculate the Macro/Micro F1 .. I thought this can be done using Sickitlearn but after checking the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) it seems that when the classification is binary the calculation will be for the positive class only .. and because of that I am trying to calculate it my self. 
As a start, I calculate the TP,TN,FP,FN using the following function:

```
def calculate(y_actual, y_pred):
    TP = 0
    FP = 0
    TN = 0
    FN = 0

    for i in range(len(y_pred)): 
        if y_actual[i]==y_pred[i]==1:    # true positive
           TP += 1
    for i in range(len(y_pred)): 
        if y_actual[i]==1 and y_pred[i]==0:   
           FN += 1
    for i in range(len(y_pred)): 
        if y_actual[i]==y_pred[i]==0:    # true negative
           TN += 1
    for i in range(len(y_pred)): 
        if y_actual[i]==0 and y_pred[i]==1:
           FP += 1

    return(TP, FP, TN, FN)
```

So in order to compute the Micro/ Macro F1 I need to compute the precision and recall for each class separately (which I don't know how!) and then it ,as an example, F1 Macro can be computed like follows ( if I understand it correctly) :

```
F1 for class one: 2(precision*recall)/(precision+recall)
F1 for class two: 2(precision*recall)/(precision+recall)
F1 Macro = (F1 for class one + F1 for class two)/2
```

a reference can be found [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.8244&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for computing F1Macro&Micro

So, is there a way to compute these measures (TP/TN/FP/FN & precision & recall) for each class separately given the function above (calculate)? 
any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use scikit-learn's routine. Set `pos_label=None` if you want to use a specified average over a binary problem. However, those measures aren't especially useful. Micro-averaged F1 for a binary or multiclass problem is identical to plain old accuracy. Macro-averaged recall, also known as *balanced accuracy*, is popular and more useful than macro-averaged F1 for a binary problem.